# Is there a Singleton that raises events?

Tags: vb.net

I have a singleton class, but I want its object to be able to raise events.
My current singleton code is as follows:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly _instance As New Lazy(Of WorkerAgent)(Function() New _
    WorkerAgent(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)

Private Sub New()
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As WorkerAgent
    Get
        Return _instance.Value
    End Get
End Property
```

Whenever I change `ReadOnly _instance As New..` into `ReadOnly WithEvents _instance As New...`

I get an error saying `ReadOnly is not valid on a WithEvents deceleration`

Although I can create the instance in the property itself, but I liked the above code because it is using .NET `Lazy` keyword which probably have great multithreading benefits.

Comment: The whole point of a singleton is that it is a single object of a type. If it's a single object of a type then it's an object of a type, so why would raising of events be any different to any other object of any other type?

Comment: Your issue has nothing whatsoever to do with singletons. The issue is exactly what the error message says: you cannot declare a field both `ReadOnly` and `WithEvents`. That's true of any field of any type, regardless of whether it's a singleton or not.

Comment: Looking more closely at your code, I'm not sure that your question even makes sense at all.  Is that code inside the `WorkerAgent` class?  If so then why would you be trying to handle events of an object of that type inside the type anyway? Consumers of your class will get an instance from that `Instance` property and it's then up to them to handle events of that object. They can assign it to a `WithEvents` variable if they need to handle its events.

Comment: Do you need to use `Lazy(Of T)`? Why not just test for `_instance is Nothing` in `Property Instance()`?

Comment: @SSS Yea I think I will do it this way since there seem to be no other way. Thanks mate for replying though

Comment: @jmcilhinney when you say `Consumers of your class will get an instance from that Instance property and it's then up to them to handle events of that object. They can assign it to a WithEvents variable if they need to handle its events.` Well can you please tell me how users of this class can use `WithEvents` keyword? I can only say SingletonClass.Instance , where would WithEvents go then?

Comment: I did so over half an hour ago.

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes I see it now...you didnt need to write all this code though, this line `Private WithEvents agent As WorkerAgent = WorkerAgent.Instance` is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot! I will mark it as answered

Comment: I don't know what you don't know. The fact that you asked the question you did suggests that you aren't clear on the difference between raising events and handling them. I post what I feel is appropriate to get across the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I really appreciate the effort so thanks for that! My issue was not handling the event or raising it (per se), but rather how singletons can raise event using `.Instance` property, should have uploaded the whole class, my bad

Comment: They don't raise events using `Instance`. That's the point. `Instance` is simply a property that returns an instance of that type. It's no different to any other property or method that does that. You were trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. If you already knew how to handle events then you already knew how to handle events of a singleton. Just replace `WorkerAgent.Instance` in my code with `New WorkerAgent` or `SomeMethodOrPropertyThatReturnsAnInstance()` and what's the difference? There isn't any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your question as asked but it demonstrates why that question doesn't make sense.  It also requires a fair chunk of code so posting in a comment wasn't really an option.  This is how your singleton class would raise events, i.e. just like any other class, and how a consumer would handle those events, i.e. just like for any other type.

Singleton:

```
Public Class WorkerAgent

    Private Shared ReadOnly _instance As New Lazy(Of WorkerAgent)

    Private _text As String

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As WorkerAgent
        Get
            Return _instance.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
        Set
            If _text <> Value Then
                _text = Value
                OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event TextChanged As EventHandler

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent TextChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note that the instance event is raised when the instance property changes, just as for any other type, singleton or not.

Consumer:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents agent As WorkerAgent = WorkerAgent.Instance

    Private Sub agent_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles agent.TextChanged
        '...
    End Sub

End Class
```

The field that the single instance is assigned to is where `WithEvents` gets used.  As your error message states, that field cannot be declared `ReadOnly` too.  If they want a `ReadOnly` field then they need to use `AddHandler` to handle events.